# Memory Error in Python when trying to sum through Numpy Ndarray Object

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, multidimensional-array

I have a huge numpy ndarray (called `mat` and of the shape 700000 x 6000) of which I want to sum through the columns and find the nonzero indices.

I want to sum through it like so:

```
x =  np.sum(mat[:,y], axis=1)
indices = np.nonzero(x)
```

But the first line immediately gives me an instant Memory Error. Is there a way I can go around using np.sum and do it another way that makes this calculation possible?

Comment: Assuming `y` is an integer `np.sum(mat[:,y], axis=1)` produces a `ValueError` because `mat[:,y]` has shape `(7000000,)`. Are you doing `mat[:, :y]` instead (slicing up to the `y`th column)?

Comment: Assuming your matrix contains standard floating point numbers, the pure matrix data will occupy almost 32 GB of memory.  Depending on the hardware you are on, it might not be a good idea to do operations on a data set of this size purely in memory.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. See Sven Marnach's comment, it is possible that your data set is too large for your hardware
2. See ajcr's comment, what you want to do is not feasible the way you try do do it because the notation `mat[:,an_index]` gives you back an array of dimensionality one, whose *only* axis is `axis=0`

Another problem is the nature of your array, if it is an array of floating point numbers the probability that the sum of 700,000 entries is *exactly* equal to zero is close to zero... it's not impossible of course, but unlikely for certain it is.

That said, if you can reduce your data set or improve your hardware, you can do like this

```
In [39]: a = np.zeros((10,5))

In [40]: for i in range(5): a[3,i]=1+2*i if i != 3 else 0.0

In [41]: a
Out[41]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  3.,  5.,  0.,  9.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [42]: np.sum(a,axis=0)
Out[42]: array([ 1.,  3.,  5.,  0.,  9.])

In [43]: np.nonzero(np.sum(a,axis=0))
Out[43]: (array([0, 1, 2, 4]),)

In [44]:
```